# Python Equivalent To PHP True False line

Tags: php, python

In PHP, you would do something like:

```
$answer = ($x != null) ? true : false
```

instead of doing:

```
if($x != null) { 
    $answer = true;
} else {
    $answer = false;
}
```

Is there anyway to do this in python? I've tried to google and to search in here but I couldn't find anything, plus google doesn't take symbols into searching. 
You might say, why didn't you google search it by name? Well I do not know what that type of line code is called.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator

Comment: Thank you aldrin27, that really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a ternary conditional operator in Python for the above code, You can do something like:

```
answer = True if x is not None else False # Using ternary conditional operator
```

**Note:** Same code can be written using the below line if ternary operator is not to be used

```
answer = x is not None # returns True/False
```

Comment: That's a long way of writing `answer = x is not None`.